# Foreach object is more faster than foreach -parallel?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, foreach, parallel-processing

I am just starting using powershell and I wonder why my parallel srcipt is more slower than my normal foreach object script?

My script for my normal foreachobject:

```
function Get-ADUsers {  #get all users in nested groups }

 function Get-NestedGroupUsers {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
    )
    $storageHolder = @()
    # $storageHolder | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\AD User Lists\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force 
    $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL 
    $groupList |  ForEach-Object { 
        $allusers = Get-ADUsers -GroupName $_
        $storageHolder += $allusers  
       
    }
    $storageHolder | select ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet  |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

My script for foreach -parallel (I store the function inside psm1 then import here.)

```
Function Get-Members {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
    )
    $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL 
    $storageHolder = $groupList |  ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        Import-Module -Name "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\Get-ADUserMembers.psm1" 
        Get-ADUserMembers -GroupName $_ | Select-Object ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
    }   -ThrottleLimit 5
    
    $storageHolder |  Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\AD User Lists\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force

}
```

The script or my get-adusers (get all the users in nested groups)

```
 function Get-ADUsers { 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline = $true, mandatory = $true)][String] $GroupName
    ) 
    [int]$circular = $null

    # result holder
    $resultHolder = @()
        $table = $null 
        $nestedmembers = $null 
        $adgroupname = $null     
  function Get-ADUsers { 
    param ( 
        [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline = $true, mandatory = $true)][String] $GroupName
    ) 
    [int]$circular = $null

    # result holder
    $resultHolder = @()
        $table = $null 
        $nestedmembers = $null 
        $adgroupname = $null     

        # get members of the group and member of
        $ADGroupname = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members

        # list all members as list (no headers) and save to var
        $memberof = $adgroupname | select -expand memberof 
       
        if ($adgroupname) {  
            if ($circular) { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -recursive 
                $circular = $null 
            } 
            else { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | sort objectclass -Descending
                # if get adgroupmember returns nothing, it uses the members for ordinary getADGroup
                if (!($nestedmembers)) {
                    $unknown = $ADGroupname | select -expand members
                    if ($unknown) {
                        $nestedmembers = @()
                        foreach ($member in $unknown) {
                            $nestedmembers += get-adobject $member
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            # loops through each member
            ForEach($nestedmember in $nestedmembers){ 
                # creates the properties into a custom object. 
                $Props = @{
                    Type            = $nestedmember.objectclass;
                    Name            = $nestedmember.name;
                    DisplayName     = "";
                    ParentGroup     = $ADgroupname.name;
                    Enabled         = "";
                    Nesting         = $nesting;
                    DN              = $nestedmember.distinguishedname;
                    Comment         = ""
                    EmployeeNumber  = "";
                    LastLogonDate   = "";
                    PasswordLastSet = "";
                } 
                # if member object is a user
                if ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "user") { 
                    # saves all the properties in the table. 
                    $nestedADMember = get-aduser $nestedmember.Name -properties enabled, displayname, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    $table = new-object psobject -property $props 
                    $table.enabled = $nestedadmember.enabled
                    $table.name = $nestedadmember.samaccountname
                    $table.displayname = $nestedadmember.displayname
                    $table.EmployeeNumber = $nestedadmember.EmployeeNumber
                    $table.LastLogonDate = $nestedadmember.LastLogonDate
                    $table.PasswordLastSet = $nestedadmember.PasswordLastSet

                    #save all in 1 storage
                    $resultHOlder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment , EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                } 


                # if member object is group
                elseif ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "group") {  
                    $table = new-object psobject -Property $props 
                    # if circular, meaning the groups member of list contains one of its members. 
                    # e.g. if group 2 is a member of group 1 and group 1 is a member of grou 2
                    if ($memberof -contains $nestedmember.distinguishedname) { 
                        $table.comment = "Circular membership" 
                        $circular = 1 
                    } 
                    # for circular output
                    #$table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment 
                    #calling function itself
                    $resultHOlder += Get-ADUsers -GroupName $nestedmember.distinguishedName                             
                } 
                else { 
                    if ($nestedmember) {
                        $table = new-object psobject -property $props
                        $resultHolder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 



    return   $resultHOlder

}
function Get-NestedGroupUsers {
    param ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$searchFileURL
    )
    $storageHolder = @()
    # $storageHolder | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\AD User Lists\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force 
    $groupList = Get-Content $searchFileURL #| ForEach-Object { $_ }
    $groupList |  ForEach-Object { 
        $allusers = Get-ADUsers -GroupName $_
        $storageHolder += $allusers  
       
    }
    $storageHolder | select ParentGroup, Name, EmployeeNumber, Enabled, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet  |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\demandx\Desktop\$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}



        # get members of the group and member of
        $ADGroupname = get-adgroup $groupname -properties memberof, members

        # list all members as list (no headers) and save to var
        $memberof = $adgroupname | select -expand memberof 
       
        if ($adgroupname) {  
            if ($circular) { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -recursive 
                $circular = $null 
            } 
            else { 
                $nestedMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | sort objectclass -Descending
                # if get adgroupmember returns nothing, it uses the members for ordinary getADGroup
                if (!($nestedmembers)) {
                    $unknown = $ADGroupname | select -expand members
                    if ($unknown) {
                        $nestedmembers = @()
                        foreach ($member in $unknown) {
                            $nestedmembers += get-adobject $member
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            # loops through each member
            ForEach($nestedmember in $nestedmembers){ 
                # creates the properties into a custom object. 
                $Props = @{
                    Type            = $nestedmember.objectclass;
                    Name            = $nestedmember.name;
                    DisplayName     = "";
                    ParentGroup     = $ADgroupname.name;
                    Enabled         = "";
                    Nesting         = $nesting;
                    DN              = $nestedmember.distinguishedname;
                    Comment         = ""
                    EmployeeNumber  = "";
                    LastLogonDate   = "";
                    PasswordLastSet = "";
                } 
                # if member object is a user
                if ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "user") { 
                    # saves all the properties in the table. 
                    $nestedADMember = get-aduser $nestedmember.Name -properties enabled, displayname, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    $table = new-object psobject -property $props 
                    $table.enabled = $nestedadmember.enabled
                    $table.name = $nestedadmember.samaccountname
                    $table.displayname = $nestedadmember.displayname
                    $table.EmployeeNumber = $nestedadmember.EmployeeNumber
                    $table.LastLogonDate = $nestedadmember.LastLogonDate
                    $table.PasswordLastSet = $nestedadmember.PasswordLastSet

                    #save all in 1 storage
                    $resultHOlder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment , EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                } 


                # if member object is group
                elseif ($nestedmember.objectclass -eq "group") {  
                    $table = new-object psobject -Property $props 
                    # if circular, meaning the groups member of list contains one of its members. 
                    # e.g. if group 2 is a member of group 1 and group 1 is a member of grou 2
                    if ($memberof -contains $nestedmember.distinguishedname) { 
                        $table.comment = "Circular membership" 
                        $circular = 1 
                    } 
                    # for circular output
                    #$table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment 
                    #calling function itself
                    $resultHOlder += Get-ADUsers -GroupName $nestedmember.distinguishedName                             
                } 
                else { 
                    if ($nestedmember) {
                        $table = new-object psobject -property $props
                        $resultHolder += $table | select type, name, displayname, parentgroup, nesting, enabled, dn, comment, EmployeeNumber, LastLogonDate, PasswordLastSet
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 



    return   $resultHOlder

}
```

Parallel result

```
-------------------------------------------
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 1
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 283
Ticks             : 622833415
TotalDays         : 0.000720872008101852
TotalHours        : 0.0173009281944444
TotalMinutes      : 1.03805569166667
TotalSeconds      : 62.2833415
TotalMilliseconds : 62283.3415
```

Non parallel Result

```
-------------------------------------------
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 35
Milliseconds      : 322
Ticks             : 353221537
TotalDays         : 0.00040882122337963
TotalHours        : 0.00981170936111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.588702561666667
TotalSeconds      : 35.3221537
TotalMilliseconds : 35322.1537
```

Comment: some processes simply don't lend themselves to running in parallel. some methods of parallelization have significant overhead. you seem to have run into one or more of those gotchas.

Comment: There is overhead in importing a module. You’re doing that in each scope instead of once in the single thread

Comment: Unless you are doing a lot of CPU processing of data that you had already loaded then the overhead of multithreading is usually slower.

Comment: @DougMaurer Unfortunately this overhead cannot be avoided (currently), see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10429

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR:

There are 3 reasons:

1. To take full advantage of `ForEach-Object -Parallel` performance, the processing time of the Script Block needs to be significantly larger than the time to set up the thread and environment.
2. The `Import-Module` will introduce an overhead.
3. Both these factors individually are small, but multiply them by 1000 or a larger number, and they become big.

---

`ForEach-Object -Parallel` runs very different than a normal `ForEach-Object`.

First, a normal `ForEach-Object` runs inside your current PowerShell thread with access to all the variables, loaded memory, and pipelining. This is fine for 98% of all the jobs we run, and 1 second execution times are ok. In the 2% of times that we have a process that is super CPU intensive that maxes out a single CPU Core and runs forever, or we need to wait for responses (e.g. API requests) when other execution can take place, then `-Parallel` is what we need to look at.

The idea behind Parallel execution is to take advantage of your brand new AMD Ryzen™ Threadripper™ 3990X with 64 Cores/128 Threads, and split your process into separate "Jobs" that cand run across multiple CPU Cores and multiple threads at the same time. This could increase your speeds by orders of magnitude e.g. potentially 128 times faster.

To achieve this, `ForEach-Object -Parallel` creates a new "Job" for each script block you execute, and starts spreading the Jobs across CPU Cores for execution. This is great when you have long running CPU bound processes, but when you have very short and small Jobs you hit the crux of Parallel execution, where the setup takes more time than the actual execution. `ForEach-Object -Parallel` has to completely set up your environment for each "Job" you run, e.g. it has to spin up multiple new threads and multiple new PowerShell instances for every Job to run in.

To illustrate the amount of setup time needed, If we wrote "Hello World" once to the current thread it takes 1 milisecond:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { Write-Host "Hello World" }
Hello World

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 1
TotalMilliseconds : 1.9798
```

To run 1 single "Hello World" in Parallel takes 26 miliseconds:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host "Hello World" } }
Hello World

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 26
TotalMilliseconds : 26.052
```

That means that it spent about 25ms spinning up a new thread, and setting up the environment and 1 ms of actual work.

To write it 100 times on the currently running thread takes about 83ms:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..100 | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "Hello World" } }
Hello World
...
Hello World
Hello World

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 83
TotalMilliseconds : 83.1846
```

Running in `-Parallel` with a `-ThrottleLimit 5` takes 294ms:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..100 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Write-Host "Hello World" }  -ThrottleLimit 5 }
Hello World
...
Hello World
Hello World

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 294
TotalMilliseconds : 294.3205
```

This goes to show how running in Parallel can be bad for tiny individual operations. But on the flip side, if you have something that takes 1 second to run, you can start to see how it works better:

e.g. run 5 processes that take 1 second each. First on a single thread:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..5 | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 } }

Seconds           : 5
Milliseconds      : 46
TotalSeconds      : 5.046348
TotalMilliseconds : 5046.348
```

As expected, it takes just over 5 seconds. Now, in Parallel:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 } -ThrottleLimit 5 }

Seconds           : 1
Milliseconds      : 73
TotalSeconds      : 1.0732423
TotalMilliseconds : 1073.2423
```

It completes in just over a second. If the processing time takes *significantly* more time than the setup time, then `-Parallel` is useful.

Also, in your case, not only do you have extra overhead of the setup time, but loading a module (needed to set up the new environment), adds significantly more time to the `ForEach-Object -Parallel` version.

For example, lets import a module `AzureAD` *inside* our `ForEach-Object` script 5 times:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..5 | ForEach-Object { Import-Module AzureAD } }

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 18
TotalSeconds      : 0.0185406
TotalMilliseconds : 18.5406
```

And now with `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

```
PS C:\> Measure-Command { 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { Import-Module AzureAD } -ThrottleLimit 5 }

Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 125
TotalSeconds      : 0.1256923
TotalMilliseconds : 125.6923
```

We can see that there is a significant difference because it has to load the module 5 times as opposed to only a single time inside the thread, then noticing that it is still loaded, and not re-loading it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This one helped me so much on understanding things.